# php registeration form submits with no error, but I dont recieve any email

Tags: php, forms, captcha

There is a PHP form on our non-profit site that was recently changed. Once we fill out the form and click submit, the forms goes through and we dont see any error, but on the other end we dont receive any email that a application was submitted. I was able to understand that an issue with store_it.php is occurring, and I tried to look into it (not a great PHP person) but I wasn't able to see what the error is. The same form without the CAPTCHA filed was working before, but this new one is giving errors.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<?php
$name = empty($_POST["name"]) ? "" : $_POST["name"];
$lname = empty($_POST["lname"]) ? "" : $_POST["lname"];
$email = empty($_POST["email"]) ? "" : $_POST["email"];
$age = empty($_POST["age"]) ? "-" : $_POST["age"];
$education = empty($_POST["education"]) ? "-" : $_POST["education"];
$country = empty($_POST["country"]) ? "-" : $_POST["country"];
$city = empty($_POST["city"]) ? "-" : $_POST["city"];
$phone = empty($_POST["phone"]) ? "-" : $_POST["phone"];
$zip = empty($_POST["zip"]) ? "-" : $_POST["zip"];
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
$email = "-";
}
if(!$name || !$lname || !$email || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
  session_start();
  if(isset($_POST["captcha"])&&$_POST["captcha"]!=""&&$_SESSION["code"]==$_POST["captcha"])
  {
    //Captcha is OK Do nothing
  }
  else
  {
   // die("Wrong Code Entered");
    //Code is not correct
    header("location:register.php?name=$name&lname=$lname&age=$age&education=$education&country=$country&city=$city&email=$email&phone=$phone&zip=$zip");
  }

}
else
{
 $file = "People.txt";
if($name == "123456" && $lname == "123456" && $email == "123456@123456.com")
{
 $a = fopen($file, "r");
 echo "<table border='1'>";
 echo "<tr><th>نام</th><th>نام خانوادگی</th><th>ایمیل</th><th>سن</th><th>تحصیلات</th><th>کشور</th><th>شهر</th><th>تلفن</th><th>کدپستی</th></tr>";
 while(!feof($a))
 {
  $columns = explode('%%%', fgets($a));
  if(!empty($columns[0]))
  {
  echo "<tr><td>".$columns[0]."</td><td>".$columns[1]."</td><td>".$columns[2]."</td><td>".$columns[3]."</td><td>".$columns[4]."</td><td>".$columns[5]."</td><td>".$columns[6]."</td><td>".$columns[7]."</td><td>".$columns[8]."</td></tr>";
  }
  }
 echo "</table>";
 fclose($a);
 echo "<form action=\"register.php\">\n";
 echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add another\">\n";
 echo "</form>\n";

}
else
{
//Write to file
 $a = fopen($file, "a");
 fwrite($a,$name."%%%");
 fwrite($a,$lname."%%%");
 fwrite($a,$email."%%%");
 fwrite($a,$age."%%%");
 fwrite($a,$education."%%%");
 fwrite($a,$country."%%%");
 fwrite($a,$city."%%%");
 fwrite($a,$phone."%%%");
 fwrite($a,$zip."%%%\r\n");
 fclose($a);

echo "Registration Successful.";

ob_start(); 

//Navigate
 $RegistrationAddress = "https://divineculture.itslearning.com/course/submitpersondata.aspx?CustomerID=2265&Unknown=true&CourseID=4&LanguageID=1&FirstName=".$name."&LastName=".$lname."&Email=".$email."&Save=True";

while (ob_get_status()) 
{
    ob_end_clean();
}

header( "Location: $RegistrationAddress" );
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Where is the code that sends mail?

Comment: set `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set("display_errors", 1);` You'll probably see `cannot send headers output already started`. `header()` must come before any output

Comment: This is your problem, and not likely your script:
https://divineculture.itslearning.com/course/submitpersondata.aspx

Who controls the submission ASP?